JavaFX: setting list for comboBox does not work
I am working in a JavaFX project. There I have fxml included in other fxml files. Now I need to send data from the outer controller to the inner controller. I've tried it, but the combobox looses its items as soon as the transferMethod finished.
Edit: As in the comment section advised, I switched to another import method. This import method fixes the bug with the comboBox, but causes problems with the import itself, at least in some cases. Therefore I update the MRE
Parts in use:
Import class:
    package at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Import {

    ArrayList<String> list;

    public Import() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }


}


inner.fxml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.InnerController">
    <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" prefWidth="150.0" />
</AnchorPane>


InnerController Class:
package at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InnerController {

    @FXML
    ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    ObservableList<String> observableList;

    public void setComboBoxItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(items);
        comboBox.setItems(observableList);
    }

}



outer.fxml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>


<TabPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
         fx:controller="at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.OuterController">
    <tabs>
        <Tab fx:id="efTab" closable="false" text="Einstieg">
            <fx:include fx:id="innerController" source="inner.fxml"/>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>


OuterController Class:
package at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OuterController {

    private ArrayList<String> items;


    @FXML
    private InnerController innerController;

    public void initialize(){

        if (innerController != null) {
            System.out.println("Right");
        }

        Import importData = new Import();
        items = importData.getList();

        innerController.setComboBoxItems(items);
    }
}


With this setup, I am unable to start the program, and get an Exception.

Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Pascal/IdeaProjects/fxplayground/target/classes/at/palberon/miniproqa/fxplayground/outer.fxml:11

    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2727)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2705)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2568)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2536)
    at at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground/at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.InnerController field at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.OuterController.innerController to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.FieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(FieldAccessorImpl.java:228)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.FieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(FieldAccessorImpl.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:115)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:836)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1180)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:870)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:764)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2858)
    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2654)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.HelloApplication

Process finished with exit code 1

I have an inner module, I call it a module (fxml file plus the Controller) which is included in the outer module.
In the FXML of the outer module, I include the FXML of the inner.
In the outer Controller I try to make me the inner Controller accessible.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you seem to be including EFController in the FXML file, im taking a guess just from the Console Output you provided and then you are creating a new instance of the same controller in the initialize method of the AbfragenController

Create and post a [mre].

@James_D Edited to MRE

@Anon I now provide an MRE in my post

change this line <fx:include  source="inner.fxml"/>   to this <fx:include  fx:id="inner" source="inner.fxml"/>  and leave only these lines on the  initialize() method from OuterController Import importData = new Import();    items = importData.getList();   innerController.setComboBoxItems(items); and add @FXML to this private InnerController innerController;

@Anon I now have a second problem, should I open another question or do an edit?
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.InnerController field at.palberon.miniproqa.fxplayground.OuterController.innerController to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
(I switched the inner and out xml a bit)

Please [edit] your question to show your revised [mre] and then error.

@trashgod Done!

See the documentation and example cited here.

the way you named your fx id <fx:include fx:id="innerController" source="inner.fxml"/> change the name to fx:id="inner" the reason is because in the controller class you have innerController if you want to keep the fx:id="innerController" then the you need to change the name of the field in OuterController  to innerControllerController

for a more visual answer see here
